# fix error 404 with practice basic spring-mvc-app

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

I study Java and  use the tutorial and ran into a problem "error 404 " with description : "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists." making "hello world" with web.xml, pom.xml, applicationContextMVC.xml, jsp-file and contoller(java class) + html file(view). It's elementary programm.

To solve the problem I used the Internet, some chats with java guru, but it didn’t do any good :(

My app use spring-webmvc, spring-web, spring-context, spring-core <- 6.0.5 version also maven(ide) and tomcat 9.0.73 ; java 17

Some screens: [click](https://imgbox.com/gallery/edit/q9V4sAhimH/PyNq9HfrHyrZ3iNS)

My suspicions of Tomcat or maven-war-plugin...

I'd appreciate any help

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.

Answer (score -1):

Problem solvded!

Because i use Thymeleaf version 3.1.1 and and i wrote in pom.xml version for  spring-core, spring-context,spring-wrv,spring-webmvc version 6.0.5.

Solving is replacing 6.0.6 to 5.3.24 in pom.xml